# karate - Can we fetch data from excel file in karate? if yes then can we set the fetch data in examples in scenario outline?

Tags: karate

```
 Examples:
      |sku_code |property_code |sale_price |override_source|persistent_override | stay_date|
      |'48'     | '0001661'    |  2000     |'DASHBOARD'    | 'true'             |   2      |
```

like I have this data hardcoded , I want this data to fetched from excel sheet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `csv` to do it using **Dynamic scenario outline** in karate

Example from karate demo:

```
Scenario Outline: cat name: <name>      
 Given url demoBaseUrl 
 And path 'cats' 
 And request { name: '<name>', age: <age> } 
 When method post 
 Then status 200 
 And match response == { id: '#number', name: '<name>' } 
 Examples: 
 | read('kittens.csv') |
```

Links:

[Dynamic csv demo](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/outline/dynamic-csv.feature)

[Dynamic scenario outline doc](https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline)

Comment: Thanks alot  for the answer, but i have one more query that  if i want to access selected columns in the csv file(like it have 10 columns and i have to access 2 and 3 columns only), then is it possible?

Comment: Technically your csv will be converted into json array. so you can use jsonpath to extract any data you want.